# How to propagate iterated element to Collectors.toMap()

Tags: lambda, collections, java-8

I am having a use case where I need to iterate over a list and apply a function over each item of list and convert it into a map of returned value -> iterated item.

```
List<ListObject> listObjectList = new ArrayList<>();
```

// consider above list contain object of type ListObject

I have a function called "someFunc" which returns object of type X.

```
class X {

    int id;

    public int getId(){

        return this.id;
    }
}

private X someFunc(ListObject obj) {

    ///...

    return new X();
}
```

I am using following :

```
listObjectList.stream().map(p -> someFunc(p)).collect(Collectors.toMap(X::getId, p));
```

When I am trying above, it seems that "p" is not propagated in collect function. 
Could anyone tell me how to populate a map of following syntax:

```
Map< Integer, ListObject > map;
```

Comment: Please indent your code. It's very hard to read in its current state.

Comment: `Collectors.toMap(X::getId, p)` this would not even compile

Comment: That’s the point of `map`; it will replace the stream element with the result of the function evaluation. When you don’t want that, just don’t use it. Use `Map<Integer, ListObject> map = listObjectList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> someFunc(p).getId(), p -> p));`

Comment: `Collectors.grouppingBy(X::getId)`

Comment: The use of .map() function is not to create a map, but rather evaluate your input or populate different objects based on the input paramters.